# How to save data when you tried to reference the schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to save information from a book that contains in its eschema auhtor and genre that I have it referenced in different files.

The problem is that when I make the reference in the main eschema. The book to have the reference of the author and the genre with the created book only keeps me the information of the book but does not make reference neither to the gender nor to the author

**book.js**

```
   const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Author', 
  },
  numberInStock: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
    default: '/path/to/default/image.png',
  },
  genre: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Genre',  
  },
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Books', bookSchema);
```

**author.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const authorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  publicatons: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Book',
  }],
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Author', authorSchema);
```

**createBook.ejs**

```
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h1>Add a New Book</h1>
            <form action="/books/new/create" method="post">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="book_name"> Book Name: </label>
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="name">
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Author</label>
                            <select class="form-control"  name="<%= author._id %>">
                            <% author.forEach(function(authors){ %>
                            <option><%= authors._id %></option>
                            <% }); %>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Genre</label>
                            <select class="form-control"  name="<%= genre._id %>">
                            <% genre.forEach(function(genres){ %>
                            <option><%= genres.name %></option>
                            <% }); %>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="numberInStock">Number in stock: </label>
                            <input type="number"  class="form-control" name="numberInStock">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="image">Image: </label>
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="image">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the part of the front where I try to send the data to the backent, but only manage to save, the name, image, quantity but not the referenced data.

**controller.js**

```
   const create = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: 'No data',
    });
  }
  const book = new Books(req.body);
  book.save((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: err.message,
      });
    }


    return res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Book created succesfully',
      result,

    });
  });
};
```

**Routes controller**

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();
const bookController = require('../controllers/book');
const booksave = require('../controllers/create');
const authorController = require('../controllers/author');
const genreController = require('../controllers/genre');

router.get('/books/home/:page', bookController.list);

router.get('/books/new', bookController.createTemplate);
router.post('/books/new/create', booksave.create);

router.get('/books/details/:id', bookController.bookDetail);

router.get('/books/new/create/genre', genreController.createGenreTemplate);
router.post('/books/new/genre', genreController.createGenre);

router.get('/books/new/create/author', authorController.createAuthorTemplate );
router.post('/books/new/author', authorController.createAuthor);




module.exports = router;
```

**create new book render**

```
controller.createTemplate = (req, res) => {
  Author.find({}, (err, allAuthors) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      Genre.find({}, (err, allGenres) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          res.render('new', { author: allAuthors, genre: allGenres });
        }
      })

    }
  });
};
```

technically what I hope to obtain is that when I save the information of the book this has a reference to its author and to the genre and automatically the author has a references to the books that are referenced with the same

Comment: Are you rendering createBook.ejs with `author` and `genre` ?

Comment: @MoadEnnagi But author and gender are the models my controller is that controls the request of the ejs

Comment: I meant with the documents you're looping through in your view, your view (createBook.ejs) has to be aware of the variable you're using. Could you show the route handler that renders createBook.ejs ?

Comment: @MoadEnnagi I already edited the question and put the route manager, but the route manager works perfectly, I do not get an error in the console

Comment: This does not show what you are rendering, what does `createTemplate()` render (res.render I assume), if this is where you are rendering the form ? My point is if you're not rendering any documents with your response, your template (view) will not know about `author` and `genre`

Comment: `const book = new Books(req.body);` is it books or `Book` ? you have `ref: 'Book'` in  `authorSchema`

Comment: @MoadEnnagi I already fix  `ref: 'Books'` but keeps only the book does not save data about the author

Comment: Are you responding with json in `bookController.createTemplate` ?

Comment: @MoadEnnagi I just edited the question and put the one where I put the render

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name attribute in `<select class="form-control"  name="<%= genre._id %>">` to `name='author'` same as in your `bookSchema`, and in `<select class="form-control"  name="<%= genre._id %>">` to `name='genre'`.
The problem is your sending a post request with the following body :

```
{ name: /*value*/ , <%= author._id%>: /*value*/, <%= genre._id%>: /*value*/, numberInStock: /*value*/, image: /*image*/ }
```

The constructor of your `Book` model recognizes `name, numberInStock and image`, but not `<%=author_id%> and <%=genre._id%>`.
Change this also:

```
author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Author'
  },
genre: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Genre'
}
```

to

```
author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: ref: 'Author'
}
genre: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Genre'
}
```

You also need to pass `genre._id` instead of `genres.name`, and `author._id`as `value` attributes like this :

```
<form action="/books/new/create" method="post">
    <select name="author">
    <% author.forEach(function(authors){ %>
      <option value="<%= authors._id %>" ><%= authors.name %></option>
    <% }); %>
    </select>
    <select name="genre">
    <% genre.forEach(function(genres){ %>
      <option value="<%= genres._id %>" ><%= genres.name %></option>
    <% }); %>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Success</button>
</form>
```

Comment: when I make that change I get this error `error: "Books validation failed: genre: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "triller" at path "genre""`

Comment: You need to pass `genre._id` because you have a reference on `Genre` model, or pass `genre.name`, but query on `Genre.find({name: req.body.genre})` and pass `genre._id`

Comment: the same result does not keep the book with the information of the genre and author

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(req.body)` inside `controller.createTemplate` ?

Comment: this is what I get `{ name: 'Digital Fortress', numberInStock: '', image: '' }`

Comment: Could you try new answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Of the values of the front I'm just getting

```
{name: 'Digital Fortress', numberInStock: '', image: ''}


const create = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: 'No data received',
    });
  }
  const book = new Books(req.body); 
  book.save((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: err.message,
      });
    }

    console.log(req.body);
    return res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Book created succesfully',
      result,

    });
  });
};
```

Comment: you need value attribute for your options: `<option value=<%=authors._id%>> <%= authors._id %></option>` and `<option value=<%=genres._id%>> <%= genres.name %></option>`

Comment: @MoadEnnagi the same in the console `{ name: 'Digital Fortress', numberInStock: '', image: '' }`